# Problem with collision bounds

Tags: game-engine

I have a chain, and I need it to collide with a soft wall. Every part of this chain is a Rigid Body (physics), and its collision bound is type "triangle mesh". The problem with this type of collision bound is that the chain breaks through the wall. If I change the type to "sphere" or another collision type, the parts of my chain are separated, but in this case these parts don't break through the wall, which is what I want.

What can I do to fix this? I need the parts of my chain together, but, at the same time, I need the chain to impact the wall without breaking through it.

Important: the wall can't be rigid, it has to be soft.

I uploaded my file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28965
(move with arrow keys, T and R)

Another problem is when I press <kbd>P</kbd> to start the game engine, it happens that my chain cannot move at any point; it's as if there were a invisible obstacle, and I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I tried to stabilize it as much as I could and made some changes (all documented in the file). Is this what you want? [file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CS1BKUWx6eEZMUTg/edit?usp=sharing). I guess the question is a bit too unspecific right now to write a clean answer. Note that collision may still fail in some circumstances (real time trade-off).

Comment: Come to think of it.. here is another idea using only capsules and rigid body joints. [file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CSTBiV1QxaFBnd0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Short video to display how it should look like. Tested with windows and linux builds of 2.70a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CbF9SS1JqVVc0UGs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you user2859! Can you tell me how do you put internal faces inside the wall? I tried applying "Subdivide" but that only subdivide the surface.